# when using 'raise' for a user defined exception, it does not work under the 'try'

Tags: exception, raise

need your kind help! 
I have defined a new Exception called 'UnderAge'  (just checking if a person is under an age limit). 
The strange thing is that when i use 'raise UnderAge as e....' it does not work under the 'try' segment. 
only the exception is working. 
Here is the code :

```
class UnderAge(Exception):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self._name = name
        self._age = age
    def __str__(self):
        return "the age %s is under 18 yo" % self._age
    def get_age(self):
        return self._age
def send_invitation(name, age):
    try:
        if int(age) < 18:
            raise UnderAge(name, age)
        else:
            print("You should send an invitation to " + name)
    except UnderAge as e:
        print("Age must be above 18 but now age is  %s." % e.get_age())

def main():
    send_invitation("miri", 16)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

-----When running it i only get : 
C:\Python\Python38-32\python.exe "C:/Users/mikie/Documents/Pyton Programs/Next.py Course/Targil_3.3.2a.py"
Age must be above 18 but now age is  16.

Process finished with exit code 0

----- i should see also an output indicating the UnderAge and its relevant **str** which i have changed. 
Please help me guys:-) 
thanks, 
Mike

Answer (score 1):

false alarm - this is a normal behaviour of the raise. 
It should pop the customized exception only if there is no exception defined in the code after the 'try'.
Also, the string which overrides the__str__ can be called by e.**str**.